# Where can I find data on African higher education institutions?

Tags: data-request, africa

I am looking for data on higher education in any African countries (the more, the merrier) for a Data Science project I am working on.

This data set can include:

- Graduation rates
- Employment after graduation
- Endowment & alumni giving
- etc ...

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The World Bank data is useful, but not comprehensive. You might also want to keep an eye on data posted to [openAFRICA.net](http://openAFRICA.net) for examination & graduation results, as well as data about education facilities, resources, and staffing from some of the countries not currently covered by the World Bank datasets.

There seems to be ~218 education related datasets on openAFRICA. Here's a link: http://africaopendata.org/dataset?q=education

Answer (score 5):

What you called "higher education" the World Bank calls "[tertiary education](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Tertiary_education)".

> including universities as well as institutions that teach specific capacities of higher learning such as colleges, technical training institutes, community colleges, nursing schools, research laboratories, centers of excellence, and distance learning centers

One place to start to search is the **World Bank [Education data portal](http://datatopics.worldbank.org/education/)**.

As one example, [School enrollment, tertiary (% gross)](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SE.TER.ENRR/countries)

> Gross enrolment ratio. Tertiary (ISCED 5 and 6). Total is the total enrollment in tertiary education (ISCED 5 and 6), regardless of age, expressed as a percentage of the total population of the five-year age group following on from secondary school leaving.

Use the SEARCH window on the left-hand side and go through all the data sets that contain the word "Tertiary."

[image]

Some other datasets you may find useful:

- [Ratio of female to male tertiary enrollment (%)](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SE.SEC.PROG.MA.ZS/countries)
- [Labor force with tertiary education, female (% of female labor force)](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SL.TLF.TERT.FE.ZS)
- [Tertiary education, teachers (% female)](http://data.worldbank.org/indicator/SE.TER.TCHR.FE.ZS)
- (there are 13 in total)

Look for the DOWNLOAD DATA button and choose your format.